# ¿Dónde "certificarse"?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, django, backend

No sé si está permitido hacer este tipo de consultas aquí, pero allá va. Si no es el caso supongo que lo borrarán o será movida la pregunta.

¿Alguien podría aconsejarme algún sitio en España donde realizar algún curso (digamos más o menos "serio") y donde quede "constancia" de lo aprendido?. Estoy pensando en algo Online / a distancia, pues donde vivo me pilla muy lejos de ciudades donde ofertan este tipo de cursos presenciales. Puede ser subvencionado, o de pago si no es algo astronómico y merece la pena. Gratuito supongo que no habrá, aunque he visto algo para desempleados pero presencial.
Sería algo relacionado con Frontend / Backend, Fullstack, etc. Escucho también sugerencias respecto a esto.

Perdón por el tocho y gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Comment: le daré un +1 a tu pregunta para que tu reputación aumente y puedas entrar al chat a hacer esta pregunta por que de otro modo aquí no te será respondida y solo será cerrada

Comment: En w3schools dan cursos de HTML, php, javascript, etc... y te dan certificado